# Correction of a misconception about loudness erased by admin

Tags: discussion

In the question "What makes drum loud" I added an answer explaining why loud is not only a property of the drum and the sound that you can produce with it.

This answer was erased. The answer was followed by many comments in which I tried to explain to a user why the idea that loudness is amplitude of the sound wave is incorrect. I hope I don't have to waste time explaining why this is the case. It is true it seems counter-intuitive, it is true it is a common misconception, but for that very same reason it is useful to inform people about it.

Read, for example:

"Loudness, Its Definition, Measurement and Calculation" Harvey Fletcher and W. A Munson, Bell Laboratories. Journal of the Acoustical Society of America / Volume 5 / Issue 2.

Or I guess the Wikipedia article on Loudness could be enough.

I think that it is correct to erase the long list of comments in which I was trying to explain why loudness is not amplitude. But erasing the information from the answer is detrimental to educating people about this common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

You completely missed the point of the question.  The fact that perceived loudness does not directly correspond to the amplitude of a sound wave is at best a footnote and does not answer the question, which was about the acoustics of drums in particular.

Comment: That is a question that hardly anyone can miss what is it about. What can trivially be said about it was already said. My answer complemented the rest by clarifying a point that was totally missed by all and misunderstood by some. When you look everywhere there are short answers that are only about a small aspect of the question that has not been said.  You only erased it in a rush. The comments was what made sense to be erased. The answer you didn't really thing about it.

Comment: The fact is, that the answer to some questions is that the question is not correctly formulated. My answer explained why is that the case. Moreover the mistake that made the question not correctly formulated was explicitly included in otherwise correct answers. This makes it important to clarify the error.

Comment: @FranklinVP A simple comment on the question would have sufficed if you felt so strongly about it.  Your post did not answer the question and that's why it was removed.